# pixel error numix

Tags: design

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with the numix-gtk theme from the official repos.
But I see a pixel error how can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with a newer version from Numix official PPA.

[image]

Delete the theme you installed from the official repos, and:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install-numix-gtk-theme
```

When you enable the theme for the first time it for some reasons will show white lines near the top border, but after a restart it will all be perfect.